# XCODE 6 Allocation Instruments don't show own class name

Tags: ios, xcode6, instruments

I create my own class : BNRItem.m

I would like to monitor this class with instrument tool for XCODE6 but I do not achieve to see my class on category column when I call it from the simulator.

When a BNRItem is created, a new line is displayed, with "malloc 4KB" on category column. **But it should be "BNRItem" instead of "malloc"** !

What I'm suppose to do ?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113652/how-do-you-find-out-what-is-retaining-an-object-in-instruments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262403/find-where-object-is-retained-with-arc

Comment: already seen but still have the problem..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same thing here with Xcode 6.2 in the simulator.

The only workaround I've found is to profile on the device. That works.